# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Hinduism's [first moderator election](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the new moderator is:

[image: TheLittleNaruto]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/4590669122240512/0).

Comment: Congratulations TheLittleNaruto. Also, Thanks to both user30612 and CR241 for participation.

Comment: Thanks JNat! Congratulations to TheLittleNaruto!

Answer (score 11):

First of all Thank you JNat for organizing the election event.

I would like to thank whole community for giving me this opportunity. I will do my best to justify my role. As I had said in nomination, I am always reachable at [Main chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism), feel free to ping me for any help.

Since I am new to this role, I am learning, and taking baby steps. :)

Comment: Congratulations Naruto! Looking forward to your term

Comment: Congratulations !

Comment: Congratulations and All The Best.Hope that we will achieve a great leap forward in site activities as a another mod is connected.

Comment: Congratulations and good luck!

Comment: Congratulations! By the way, what does your username mean?

Comment: @vidyarthi "Naruto" is name of the character in an anime.