# Does system also handle few flags?

Tags: discussion, support

My two recent flags were declined but I think they were valid ones.

- A Q was duplicate of 2 questions and in such cases we flag it to mod but after I flagged the Q, OP deleted it and my flag got declined:

  > May 24 at 6:30   declined - Question is deleted now by OP
- A Q was spam but OP deleted the Q after I flagged it and my flag got declined:

  > yesterday   declined - deleted by post author

Now, when I try to flag something, the system gives warning:

> Your recent flag was declined - please review it before flagging this post!

My questions are

- Were these flags handled by System or Mods?
- If mods then, weren't my flags supposed to be marked as helpful instead of declined?

Comment: Yes system declines flags when the user himself acts on a post flagged by us. I have experienced the same issue once

Comment: The comment "Question is deleted now by OP" and "deleted by post author" are diff so I doubt it..hence, confirming..after seeing comment language, looks like atleast one flag was handled by mod..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> - Were these flags handled by System or Mods?

Most of the flags are handled by moderators. However there are some exceptions like:

1. if the post is automatically flagged for low quality and gets edited, system validates the flag;
2. if the post gets 6 red flags (or a moderator's red flag) they are all automatically marked helpful,
3. if a comment flag gets too old, it is automatically disputed

etc.

> - If mods then, weren't my flags supposed to be marked as helpful instead of declined?

Here was no further action to be taken, so I declined them. But yeah I agree these flags should have been marked helpful. It was a mistake from my side.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification..

Comment: @YDS You're welcome, Also please read the last line in [this post](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2175/647) :'-)

Comment: Yeah, I m already aware of that.. :)

Comment: An apology in addition to admitting a mistake would probably have gone a long way, and yes, I'm commenting after reading the last line in the linked post. :-)