# Timeline of HSE moderators

Tags: support, moderators

(Following [this post on Literature.SE](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1788/timeline-of-literature-moderators).)

Who has moderated Hinduism Stack Exchange? What have been the moderator teams over the years since the site's creation?

Which ones were elected, and which were appointed?

Comment: I think it'll be easy to answer if we search across meta HSE

Comment: (It should also be possible to find from Wayback Machine archives of the "Moderators" tab of the Users page, and/or of election pages, if needed.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Below is the timeline with additional details!

| Moderator | Tenure | Appointment | Removal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [senshin](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/13) | 7 July 2014 to 8 Feb. 2016 | [Selected Through Self Nomination](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/131) | [Due to Inactivity](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/441/277) |
| [cheenbabes](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/39) | 7 July 2014 to 8 Feb. 2016 | [Selected Through Self Nomination](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/131) | [Due to Inactivity](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/441/277) |
| [Mr. Alien](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/124) | 7 July 2014 to 24 Feb. 2017 | [Selected Through Self Nomination](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/131) | [Resigned](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785) |
| [Keshav Srinivasan](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/36) | 6 Nov. 2014 to Present | Appointed by CM on requirement | NA |
| [Ankit Sharma](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/76) | 8 Feb. 2016 to 24 Feb. 2017 | [Appointed by CM on Requirement](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/462) | [Resigned](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/782) |
| [Pandya](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/277) | 24 Feb. 2017 to Present | [Appointed by CM on Requirement](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/780) | NA |
| [The Destroyer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/3500) | 24 Feb. 2017 to Present | [Appointed by CM on Requirement](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/780) | NA |
| [TheLittleNaruto](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/647) | 16 Feb. 2021 to Present | [Elected by Community through Election](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2174) | NA |

Comment if you find any discrepancy.

Comment: Nice answer! Is there not a post for Keshav Srinivasan?

Comment: Wow it's been more than 2 and half years already. Time does fly...